# Accessing a variable set by a view within an after_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in the process of moving from using a third-party analytics solution into something home-grown. One of the things I'm looking to do is include the page title of the rendered view into the database.

Now, I'm using a method, called within a view, to set the page title, that looks like this:

```
<% title "This is my page title" %>
```

I tried modifying the `title` method to have a variable called `@internal_page_title` set, but it wasn't available in the Application Controller's `after_filter` call. Is it possible to get information from the rendered view into an `after_filter` (or other hook that would also provide access to the `request`)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nothing satisfactory. The answer below, technically, works. But it's a lot of effort to parse the response for my uses. I was hoping there'd be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

In the `after_filter` you have access to your whole response via `self.response`. You could parse `self.response.body` for the title that you need to save to the DB.